# Reduce the size of list with Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to reduce the size (delete some elements) of an ordered list of map objects. All objects of list should be discarded unless a certain condition is met. And when that condition is met all next elements of that list should remained in the list. I have following piece of code. I want to do the same with Java 8.

```
public List<Map<String, String>> doAction(List<Map<String, String>> dataVoMap) {
    List<Map<String,String>> tempMap = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean found = false;
    for(Map<String, String> map: dataVoMap){
        if(map.get("service_id").equalsIgnoreCase("passed value") || found){
            found = true;
            tempMap.add(map);
        }
    }
    dataVoMap = tempMap;
    return dataVoMap;
}
```

Comment: This is valid Java 8 code already.

Comment: I want to do with java 8 streams. Subject updated.

Comment: They're not the appropriate tool for this job. You would need a skipWhile method, which doesn't exist. Of course you could use an IntStream to find the index of the first element satisfying the condition, and then use subList, but this would be more convoluted than what you have.

Comment: As a side note, using `very_long_expression || simple_boolean_flag` is quiet strange, as normally, you want it in the opposite order, to skip the potentially expensive expression evaluation when the simple boolean flag is `true`…

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: In addition to that your iterative code is much more readable than it's stream based counterpart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a [`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation, but an in-built implementation of that would require Java-9 and above:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> doAction(List<Map<String, String>> dataVoMap) {
    return dataVoMap.stream()
            .dropWhile(m -> !"passed value".equalsIgnoreCase(m.get("service_id")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Note*: I have made an edit to the existing code to avoid NPE when there could be a `Map` in the `List` without the key `service_id`.

Comment: Avoiding the NPE might be undesirable, if the map is not expected to have any missing keys, then you usually wouldn't want it to fail silently. Still, good answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution with using a little hack:

```java
public static List<Map<String, String>> doAction(List<Map<String, String>> dataVoMap) {
        AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        return dataVoMap.stream()
                .filter(map -> found.get() || "passed value".equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("service_id")))
                .peek(map -> found.set(true))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

If you don't need to parallel the stream you can use this solution with Java 8.